# Maven release plugin and GitHub HTTPS repository access

Tags: git, maven, https, maven-release-plugin, jgit

Is it possible to use the Maven Release plugin against a GitHub repository **without** connection via SSH?

GitHub itself is advising to use **HTTPS** for repository access and I would like to avoid having to mess around with SSH keys. You don't need SSH for pushing to the repository from the command line, so why should it be any different for the Maven Release plugin?

Ultimately this shall work from Jenkins.

I tried to use JGit as follows in my pom.xml:

```xml
<scm>
  <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/me/myproject.git</connection>
  <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/me/myproject.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <configuration>
        <providerImplementations>
          <git>jgit</git>
        </providerImplementations>
      </configuration>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-jgit</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Executing the release goal gives an error, though:

```
$ mvn release:prepare release:perform -Dresume=false -Dusername=gituser -Dpassword=gitpassword

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project myproject: An error is occurred in the checkin process:
Exception while executing SCM command. JGit checkin failure! https://gituser@github.com/me/myproject.git: https://gituser@github.com/me/myproject.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack not found -> [Help 1]
```

Am I missing something obvious or is it just not possible?

Comment: https means you are not allowed to push on Github. Why not using the correct git URL references for your scm entries like `scm:git:git@github.com:USER/repository.git`.

Comment: And dont forget to check this, in case you are not aware of ssh keys: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Comment: This is simply not true. You can do everything over HTTPS that you can do over SSH: https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/
This problem is related to the Maven release plugin and/or JGit.